# RestSharp OAuth2 Bearer Authentication Failing With Access Denied

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, restsharp

I have implemented my own custom `IAuthenticator` called `OAuth2BearerAuthenticator` which basically takes in a `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` and before any request is made, it checks if it has a valid Bearer Token - if not it will use the client credentials to go away and "Refresh" the token before proceeding with the original request.

The `Authenticate` method of this custom authenticator contains the following:

```
public void Authenticate(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
{
    if (!bearerTokenExpiration.HasValue || bearerTokenExpiration.Value < DateTime.Now)
    {
        RefreshBearerToken();
    }

    if (request.Parameters.Any(p => p.Name.Equals("Authorization", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
    {
        return;
    }

    request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", bearerToken));
}
```

I have verified that the bearer token that it is generating is valid - I can successfully request data from the API I am trying to access with the same bearer token authorization header in DHC (Chrome REST extension)

I have also verified that it is not returning early from the `if (any authorization paramaters)` statement.

However, RestSharp is failing with the response `"HTTP Basic: Access denied.\n"`

I don't know if it is relevant but the response also contains a `WWW-Authenticate` header with the value `Basic realm=\"Web Password\"`

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

Also, for Bearer token you can use one of the existing authenticators:

```
client.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(yourAccessToken);
```

Or:

```
client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(yourAccessToken, "Bearer");
```

Answer (score 27):

I think if you are are using bearer token to authenticate your request you can use this way:

```
client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", bearerToken));
```

Hope it work!

Comment: request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", bearerToken));